# MySQL trying to update a table from values stored in a temp table

Tags: mysql, select, temp-tables

I'm doing a select from a table to fill in the values to update in my permanent table. MySQL complains that "Unknown column 'rtufu.FollowUpDays' in 'field list'". What am I doing incorrectly?

```
UPDATE FollowUpTbl 
  SET 
    FollowUpDate = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL (rtufu.FollowUpDays) DAY) 
  WHERE FollowUpID IN (SELECT FollowUpID FROM RowsToUpdateFollowUps rtufu);

RowsToUpdateFollowUps (Temporary)
+------------+--------------+
| FollowUpID | FollowUpDays |
+------------+--------------+
|      64417 |           90 |
|      45508 |           90 |
+------------+--------------+

FollowUpTbl
+--------------+------------+
| FollowUpDate | FollowUpID |
+--------------+------------+
| 0000-00-00   |          1 |
| 0000-00-00   |          2 |
+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: Please show us the table schema for FollowUpTbl , and RowsToUpdateFollowUps. Is temporary table, won't purge after session closed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner joins can be used with updates.

```
UPDATE FollowUpTbl f 
INNER JOIN RowsToUpdateFollowUps rtufu ON rtufu.FollowUpID = f.FollowUpID 
SET f.FollowUpDate = DATE_ADD(
    NOW(), 
    INTERVAL (rtufu.FollowUpDays) DAY
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update FollowUpTbl as f
    inner join RowsToUpdateFollowUps as t using (FollowUpID)
set f.FollowUpDate = DATE_ADD(NOW(), interval t.FollowUpDays DAY);
```

Comment: You beat me in with a post by about 20 seconds.

Comment: @Ben Dauphinee: Sorry, I'll ask you next time before answering :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax is a little mangled. Try this.

```
UPDATE FollowUpTbl 
  SET 
    FollowUpDate = (
      SELECT
          DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL (rtufu.FollowUpDays) DAY)
          FROM RowsToUpdateFollowUps rtufu
          WHERE rtufu.FollowUpID = FollowUpTbl.FollowUpID
    );
```

Comment: ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: You might need to add a MAX() or a MIN() around the rtufu.FollowUpDays, depending on what it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

rtufu is defined in the 'inner' (aka nested) select.  It does not have visibility in the 'outer' update.